# Is there any initiative to transition all shell globs into standard regex?

Tags: shell, regular-expression, wildcards

I see many imagination between shell globs (wildcards) syntax and standard regex.

Is there (or was there) any initiative to transition all shell globs into standard regex?

By that I mean, using regex **as** shell globs; or some updated version of regex that might have came out or is planned to come out.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/927/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you could create an alternate shell and call it `/bin/myshell` but you wouldn't replace `/bin/sh` with it because any shell that uses regex instead of globs would:

1. Not be POSIX compliant
2. Break every existing script
3. Be a pain to deal with (`vi \.profile` perhaps, to escape the `.`?)

So, no; `/bin/sh` will not be replaced with a shell that uses regex's instead of globs.

Comment: Make that `^\.profile$`